# How to create a sticky video effect with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have seen that it is possible to create a sticky image effect on hover using three.js which inspired me with an idea of doing this effect over a video.

Initially, I converted the video to a gif hover the gif was stuck on the first frame. I then tried canvid.js which uses loops frames instead of video. Finally I tried to pause the video an take an image of the frame that is hovered on and then use the effect on the image.

```
/* S C R E E N S H O T */

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#heroVideo").get(0).play();
    var video = document.getElementById("heroVideo");
    var currentTime = video.currentTime
    var imgUrl = "./img/overlay.png";

    $(".hoverZone").hover(function(){
      $("img").css("opacity","1");
      function getVideoImage(path, secs, callback) {
        var me = this, video = document.createElement('video');
        video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
          if ('function' === typeof secs) {
            secs = secs(this.duration);
          }
          this.currentTime = Math.min(Math.max(0, (secs < 0 ? this.duration : 0) + secs), this.duration);
        };
        video.onseeked = function(e) {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
          canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
          callback.call(me, img, this.currentTime, e);
        };
        video.onerror = function(e) {
          callback.call(me, undefined, undefined, e);
        };
        video.src = path;
      }
      function showImageAt(currentTime) {
        var current;
        getVideoImage(
          './img/Morph.mp4',
          function(currentTime) {
            current = video.currentTime;
            return current;
          },
          function(img, secs, event) {
            if (event.type == 'seeked') {
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              li.appendChild(img);
              document.getElementById('olFrames').appendChild(li);
              var imgUrl = $('img')[0].src;
              console.log(imgUrl);
              if (current >= ++secs) {
              };
            }
          }
        );
      }
      showImageAt(currentTime);
      }, function(){
      $("img").css("opacity","0");
    });

/* D I S T O R T I O N */

    const imgSize = [1250, 10097];

    const vertex = `
          attribute vec2 uv;
          attribute vec2 position;
          varying vec2 vUv;
          void main() {
              vUv = uv;
              gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
          }
      `;
    const fragment = `
          precision highp float;
          precision highp int;
          uniform sampler2D tWater;
          uniform sampler2D tFlow;
          uniform float uTime;
          varying vec2 vUv;
          uniform vec4 res;

          void main() {

              // R and G values are velocity in the x and y direction
              // B value is the velocity length
              vec3 flow = texture2D(tFlow, vUv).rgb;

              vec2 uv = .5 * gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy ;
              vec2 myUV = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
              myUV -= flow.xy * (0.15 * 0.7);

              vec2 myUV2 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
              myUV2 -= flow.xy * (0.125 * 0.7);

              vec2 myUV3 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
              myUV3 -= flow.xy * (0.10 * 0.7);

              vec3 tex = texture2D(tWater, myUV).rgb;
              vec3 tex2 = texture2D(tWater, myUV2).rgb;
              vec3 tex3 = texture2D(tWater, myUV3).rgb;

              gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex2.g, tex3.b, 1.0);
          }
      `;
    {
      const renderer = new ogl.Renderer({ dpr: 2 });
      const gl = renderer.gl;
      document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

      // Variable inputs to control flowmap
      let aspect = 1;
      const mouse = new ogl.Vec2(-1);
      const velocity = new ogl.Vec2();
      function resize() {
        let a1, a2;
        var imageAspect = imgSize[1] / imgSize[0];
        if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
          a1 = 1;
          a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
        } else {
          a1 = (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) * imageAspect;
          a2 = 1;
        }
        mesh.program.uniforms.res.value = new ogl.Vec4(
          window.innerWidth,
          window.innerHeight,
          a1,
          a2
        );

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      }
      const flowmap = new ogl.Flowmap(gl, {
        falloff: 1.0, // size of the stamp, percentage of the size
        alpha: 0.7, // opacity of the stamp
        dissipation: 0.95// affects the speed that the stamp fades. Closer to 1 is slower
      });
      // Triangle that includes -1 to 1 range for 'position', and 0 to 1 range for 'uv'.
      const geometry = new ogl.Geometry(gl, {
        position: {
          size: 2,
          data: new Float32Array([-1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3])
        },
        uv: { size: 2, data: new Float32Array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2]) }
      });
      const texture = new ogl.Texture(gl, {
        minFilter: gl.LINEAR,
        magFilter: gl.LINEAR
      });
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => (texture.image = img);
      img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
      img.src = imgUrl;

      let a1, a2;
      var imageAspect = imgSize[1] / imgSize[0];
      if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
        a1 = 1;
        a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
      } else {
        a1 = (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) * imageAspect;
        a2 = 1;
      }

      const program = new ogl.Program(gl, {
        vertex,
        fragment,
        uniforms: {
          uTime: { value: 0 },
          tWater: { value: texture },
          res: {
            value: new ogl.Vec4(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, a1, a2)
          },
          img: { value: new ogl.Vec2(imgSize[0], imgSize[1]) },
          // Note that the uniform is applied without using an object and value property
          // This is because the class alternates this texture between two render targets
          // and updates the value property after each render.
          tFlow: flowmap.uniform
        }
      });
      const mesh = new ogl.Mesh(gl, { geometry, program });

      window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
      resize();

      // Create handlers to get mouse position and velocity
      const isTouchCapable = "ontouchstart" in window;
      if (isTouchCapable) {
        window.addEventListener("touchstart", updateMouse, false);
        window.addEventListener("touchmove", updateMouse, { passive: false });
      } else {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMouse, false);
      }
      let lastTime;
      const lastMouse = new ogl.Vec2();
      function updateMouse(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches.length) {
          e.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
          e.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
        }
        if (e.x === undefined) {
          e.x = e.pageX;
          e.y = e.pageY;
        }
        // Get mouse value in 0 to 1 range, with y flipped
        mouse.set(e.x / gl.renderer.width, 1.0 - e.y / gl.renderer.height);
        // Calculate velocity
        if (!lastTime) {
          // First frame
          lastTime = performance.now();
          lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);
        }

        const deltaX = e.x - lastMouse.x;
        const deltaY = e.y - lastMouse.y;

        lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);

        let time = performance.now();

        // Avoid dividing by 0
        let delta = Math.max(10.4, time - lastTime);
        lastTime = time;
        velocity.x = deltaX / delta;
        velocity.y = deltaY / delta;
        // Flag update to prevent hanging velocity values when not moving
        velocity.needsUpdate = true;
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
      function update(t) {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
        // Reset velocity when mouse not moving
        if (!velocity.needsUpdate) {
          mouse.set(-1);
          velocity.set(0);
        }
        velocity.needsUpdate = false;
        // Update flowmap inputs
        flowmap.aspect = aspect;
        flowmap.mouse.copy(mouse);
        // Ease velocity input, slower when fading out
        flowmap.velocity.lerp(velocity, velocity.len ? 0.15 : 0.1);
        flowmap.update();
        program.uniforms.uTime.value = t * 0.01;
        renderer.render({ scene: mesh });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why simply not use `THREE.VideoTexture()`?

Comment: @prisoner849 thank you I have tried this out, but it is not working.. i have created a new question if you could help please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834793/setting-background-video-in-canvas-using-video-texture-with-three-js-not-working